# Is it normal that I can see login info in response.config.data in my browser console?

Tags: node.js, express, axios

I am using react and express to build a log in system. I found that I could see the login info in console. (response.config.data). I think it's not safe. Is it normal?

```
exports.login = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { email, password, confirmPassword } = req.body;

    let loggedInUser;

    if (password !== confirmPassword) {
      const error = new Error('Password not matched!');
      error.statusCode = 401;
      throw error;
    }
    const user = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (!user) {
      const error = new Error('User not found');
      error.statusCode = 401;
      throw error;
    }
    console.log(user);

    loggedInUser = user;
    const isEqual = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    if (!isEqual) {
      const error = new Error('Wrong password!');
      error.statusCode = 401;
      throw error;
    }

    res.status(200).json({
      message: 'Logged in successfully',
      userId: loggedInUser._id.toString(),
    });
  } catch (err) {
    if (!err.statusCode) {
      err.statusCode = 500;
    }
    next(err);
  }
};
```

[console photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhhMM.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

it's normal and there is no danger because requests can be made by passing the relevant config to `axios` like `method` , `url` and `data` and ..., after the request is sent, in the response you can only see the information that you entered when sending the request